# Cannot create Qt qml project with Qt commercial charts

Tags: qt, qml

Getting error

> module "QtCommercial.Chart" is not installed

when trying to import

> QtCommercial.Chart 1.3

in qml file

Please help

Comment: As this is part of Digia’s commercial offering, did you try Digia support?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a commercial license, and have downloaded Charts via the Maintenance Tool... Unlike other Qt modules, Charts does not come pre-built. Only the source seems to be provided (as of Qt 5.2.1). See [Digia's QtCharts documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/QtCharts/gettingstarted.html) for instructions on how to build from source, and to include it in your project.